# What are the limitations for a custom CouchDB _id field?

Tags: couchdb, limit, couchdb-2.0

I'm going to implement my own unique `_id` fields generation algorithm in **CouchDB 2.1** and I want to figure out how much I am limited. The only [reference](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/document/common.html) about `_id` I've found is this:

> **_id** (string) – Document ID

Am I allowed to have an arbitrary long text of ASCII symbols as an `_id`? What characters are allowed?

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer but for starters, one special limitation is that if the _id begins with `_design/…` it will of course be treated specially. One might also assume (at least if taking an abundance of caution) that any docid starting with any other sort of `_` would be considered reserved.